# Vba и web парсинг

Tags: html, excel, vba

Добрый день! 
Пытаюсь разобраться в парсинге веб страниц с помощью vba. Ситуация следующая: есть сайт с полями для ввода. Все эти поля имеют один classname. Как обратитьсяк нужному полю (и написать туда чего-нибудь)? У них нет индексов или других уникальных признаков. Или может я чего-то не знаю. Спасибо заранее.

Добавил скриншот с кодом сайта, на нем как раз открывается блок с полями для ввода. Одно из этих полей я раскрыл. Другого браузера, к сожалению, нет.

[image: код сайта с нужными элементами]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался: несмотря, на то, что в коде страницы много элементов одного класса, в vba, один элемент имеющий сколько-то item’ов. 
Set x = getelementbyclassname(“classname”)

И вот у x будет item(1), item(2) и тд. Туда и передавать значения.